# Removing Tracking Spec from Ad Group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am using PHP-SDK for Facebook Ads API. While adding **tracking_specs** or **conversion_specs** to an ad group on Facebook platform, I am passing an array to relative parameters.

But when I need to remove **tracking_specs** from an ad group, setting **tracking_specs** parameters to *null, empty array, empty object* or *empty string* does not work. Not sending to parameters means not editing it. So, how should I remove **tracking_specs** from an **ad_group**?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible - you could set the tracking spec to something you actually want to track, or retire that adgroup and create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Posting an empty dictionary to an adgroup updates the tracking spec to be an empty dictionary.

For example:

```
curl \
-F 'tracking_specs={}' \
-F 'access_token=____' \
'https://graph.facebook.com/1234141'
```

Answer (score 0):

Paul, this request doesn't remove tracking specs. It seems impossible to revert to default specs after custom specs were used. Can you confirm that?